# canvas doesn't work when other div are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I got this problem: I found a very cool pen on codepen, I take it, modified, but when I put this in my html page doesn't work with other divs.
Here the pen https://jsfiddle.net/jtz21sz3/

```
<canvas id="stage" width="400" height="400">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
```

everything work, but when i try to insert a sticky menu in the top the canvas draws the circle, but I can't drag them. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9w34sd/1/

```
<div class="sticky-menu-wrapper">
   <nav class="main-menu clear">
     <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu" style="text-align:center">
       <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom" style=" text-align:left; float: left; padding-top:16px;"><a>RELEASE</a></li>
     </ul></div>
   </nav>
</div>

<canvas id="stage" width="400" height="400">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: That happens because the added elements move the canvas on the page. There's  a default setting `mouseX/Y = 0` at the definition part. These values should match with the real placement of the canvas. Also, in `getMouseXY(e)`, you're using `e.pageX/Y` to detect the mouse position, but all the math is done assuming the canvas being at `0,0`. Use `e.offsetX/Y` in `getMouseXY(e)` to get correct mouse position related to canvas. Also IE detection `if (document.all)` doesn't work properly, Chrome has implemented `document.all` too.

Comment: You can actually remove all IE detections, since everything works fine in IE>8, supporting IE8 or older doesn't make much sense, since they don't support canvas anyway ... [Here's a forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hh0w0j10/).

Comment: THAT'S TRUE! IT WORKS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `function getMouseXY(e) {` to this

```
function getMouseXY(e) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;

  if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
  if (mouseY < 0)  mouseY = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:absolute` (or `fixed`) to the nav.

```js
var stage = document.getElementById('stage');

var browserX = window.screenX;
var browserY = window.screenY;
var balls = [];
var total = 6;
var currentDrag = null;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var stageWidth = $(document).width();
var stageHeight = $(document).height();
stage.width = stageWidth;
stage.height = stageHeight;

var IE = document.all ? true : false;
if (!IE) document.addEventListener(Event.MOUSEMOVE, getMouseXY, false);
document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

window.onresize = function(event) {
  stage.width = 10;
  stage.height = 10;
  stageWidth = $(document).width();
  stageHeight = $(document).height();
  stage.width = stageWidth;
  stage.height = stageHeight;
}

generate();

var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('stage');
if (drawingCanvas.getContext) {
  var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(render, 20);
}



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    onMouseDown();
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    onMouseUp();
  });
})



function onMouseDown() {
  var j = balls.length;
  while (--j > -1) {
    var dx = mouseX - balls[j].x;
    var dy = mouseY - balls[j].y;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    if (dist < balls[j].size / 2) {
      currentDrag = balls[j];
      currentDrag.dragging = true;
      return;
    }
  }
}

function onMouseUp() {
  if (currentDrag != null) currentDrag.dragging = false;
}




function generate() {
  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var ball = {};
    ball.color = "#" + genHex();
    ball.bounce = .5 + (Math.random() * .5);
    ball.vx = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
    ball.vy = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
    ball.size = 75 - (ball.bounce * 25);
    ball.x = Math.random() * stageWidth;
    ball.y = Math.random() * stageHeight;
    balls[balls.length] = ball;
  }
}

function genHex() {
  colors = new Array(14)
  colors[0] = "0"
  colors[1] = "1"
  colors[2] = "2"
  colors[3] = "3"
  colors[4] = "4"
  colors[5] = "5"
  colors[5] = "6"
  colors[6] = "7"
  colors[7] = "8"
  colors[8] = "9"
  colors[9] = "a"
  colors[10] = "b"
  colors[11] = "c"
  colors[12] = "d"
  colors[13] = "e"
  colors[14] = "f"

  digit = new Array(5)
  color = ""
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    digit[i] = colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 14)]
    color = color + digit[i]
  }

  return color;
}

function render() {
  var isChange = (browserX != window.screenX || browserY != window.screenY);
  if (isChange) {
    var diffX = browserX - window.screenX;
    browserX = window.screenX;

    var diffY = browserY - window.screenY;
    browserY = window.screenY;
  }

  var j = balls.length;
  while (--j > -1) {
    update(balls[j]);

    if (isChange) {
      balls[j].vx += (diffX * .05);
      balls[j].vy += (diffY * .1);
    }
  }

  draw();
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight);
  var i = balls.length;
  while (--i > -1) {
    context.fillStyle = balls[i].color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, balls[i].size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
  }
}

function update(ball) {
  collisionCheck();

  var gravity = 0;
  var drag = .98;

  if (ball.dragging) {
    ball.vx = ball.x - ball.ox;
    ball.vy = ball.y - ball.oy;
    ball.ox = ball.x;
    ball.oy = ball.y;

    ball.x = mouseX;
    ball.y = mouseY;

    if ((ball.x + ball.size) > stageWidth) {
      ball.x = stageWidth - ball.size;
    } else if ((ball.x - ball.size) < 0) {
      ball.x = 0 + ball.size;
    }

    if ((ball.y + ball.size) > stageHeight) {
      ball.y = stageHeight - ball.size;
    } else if ((ball.y - ball.size) < 0) {
      ball.y = 0 + ball.size;
    }
  } else {
    ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;

    if ((ball.x + ball.size) > stageWidth) {
      ball.x = stageWidth - ball.size;
      ball.vx = -ball.vx * ball.bounce;
    } else if ((ball.x - ball.size) < 0) {
      ball.x = 0 + ball.size;
      ball.vx = -ball.vx * ball.bounce;
    }

    if ((ball.y + ball.size) > stageHeight) {
      ball.y = stageHeight - ball.size;
      ball.vy = -ball.vy * ball.bounce;
    } else if ((ball.y - ball.size) < 0) {
      ball.y = 0 + ball.size;
      ball.vy = -ball.vy * ball.bounce;
    }

    ball.vx = ball.vx * drag;
    ball.vy = ball.vy * drag + gravity;
  }
}




function collisionCheck() {
  var spring = .5;

  for (var i = 0; i < (total - 1); ++i) {
    var ball0 = balls[i];

    for (var j = i + 1; j < total; ++j) {
      var ball1 = balls[j];
      var dx = ball1.x - ball0.x;
      var dy = ball1.y - ball0.y;
      var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      var minDist = ball0.size + ball1.size;

      if (dist < minDist) {
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        var tx = ball0.x + dx / dist * minDist;
        var ty = ball0.y + dy / dist * minDist;
        var ax = (tx - ball1.x);
        var ay = (ty - ball1.y);


        ball0.x -= ax;
        ball0.y -= ay;

        ball1.x += ax;
        ball1.y += ay;


        ball0.vx -= (ax * spring);
        ball0.vy -= (ay * spring);
        ball1.vx += (ax * spring);
        ball1.vy += (ay * spring);
      }
    }
  }
}




function getMouseXY(e) {
  if (IE) {
    mouseX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
    mouseY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
  } else {
    mouseX = e.pageX
    mouseY = e.pageY
  }

  if (mouseX < 0) {
    mouseX = 0;
  }
  if (mouseY < 0) {
    mouseY = 0;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```css
#stage { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#DDD; }

.sticky-menu-wrapper {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky-menu-wrapper">
  <nav class="main-menu clear">
    <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu" style="text-align:center">
      <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom" style=" text-align:left; float: left; padding-top:16px;"><a>RELEASE</a></li>
      </ul></div>
  </nav>
</div>


<div>
  <canvas id="stage" width="400" height="400">
    <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
  </canvas>
</div>
```